# Where to store the sensitive data in vb.net securely

Tags: vb.net, security, rsa, aes, public-key-encryption

I have a vb.net application that uses my gmail smtp server settings and my password to send me the users feedback through the email, (I don't want to show my email to the users)

The problem is I want to store these data securely in the vb.net application so that It's hard for any hackers/crackers through (reverse engineering or programs like cheat engine) to get my gmail account data.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Securely in a winforms app?: Short answer: you can't. You can hide from prying eyes, but not a skilled 'hacker'. Also, using your gmail account this way is probably not a good idea for several reasons.

Comment: Okay where do you think to store it?

Comment: I don't think you should hide the email address. You are trying to solve symptoms rather than the cause; ie. because it's your gmail address you don't want to show it. Create a seprate email account and use that; let the user see it, it's no big secret.

Comment: yes i know that i can make another email but I've a situation like this and I'm asking for a solution

Comment: If you want to ignore good advice, that's up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot be 100% secure, you could store the email in a resource file and use an obsficator to make it much harder to get at the string but it is possible to break it (encrypted resource files and strings).  However Even if you used a different email address and setup a forwarding rule the password for that account could still be comprimised.  Anything you have access to in code a hacker could potentially break into as the key will be in clear text at some point.

You have a number of secure options:

1. Setup a webservice to receive your messages and email them onto you/log them to a database
2. Log your messages to a 3rd Party system (irc? news? some p2p network, IM system), and pick um the messages later.
3. Setup a Source Control/issue site for your system, google code/bitbucket/something else that has the ability to receive issues via an api.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this makes any sense but what I'd do is let the program run an external PHP script that sends the mail.

Comment: +1 because its a valid idea although maybe not very well explained. Didn't deserve anonymous downvote IMHO

Comment: I can do this but it requires a server and when the client applications number increase you will overload the server instead of dividing the job on the client pcs

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if I'm understanding your question, you don't want the password in clear text in your .exe.  Correct?

The solution is simply to ENCRYPT the string in your program, then decrypt it at runtime (pass your decrypted variable to your e-mail function).

Any two-way encryption will work.  For example:

http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/security/1240-encrypt-password.html

Comment: Not a deterrent to a determined hacker. They can decompile the EXE with Reflector and read the decryption method. Or run it in a debugger and step through the decryption and the email sending.

Answer (score 0):

As other people pointed out saving the password to your email in your application is unsafe because somebody might be able to crack your code and retrieve your password.
For logging errors, I suggest creating a very small PHP script and putting it on a PHP server. When an error occurs in your VB.NET application, the application can send data to this .php script. The script can save the data in a file or in a MySQL database.
All the things you need for sending data to PHP scripts can be found in "System. Net. WebRequest" namespace in VB.NET.
If you cannot use a PHP script, you may use a combination of IsolatedStorage ("System.IO.IsolatedStorage" namespace) and Cryptography ("System.Security.Cryptography" namespace) to save sensitive data. But, this is not completely secure to savvy attackers.